# python2.7 pip install EnvironmentError Illega byte sequence

Tags: python, pip

I have an error at `pip install pyinstaller`

Cmd quote:

> Microsoft Windows Version 6.3.9600 20
>   13 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install pyinstaller
>   Collecting pyinstaller
>   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/86/909a8c35c5471919b3854c01f43843d9b5aed0e9948b63e560010f7f3429/PyInstaller-3.3.1.tar.gz
>   (3.5MB)
>
> 1% |Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 42] Illega l byte sequence

I use python2.7 and Windows8:

> Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v. 1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

I tried to check what cause the problem all across the internet without success.

- it happend to me also at `pip install py2exe` command
- it doesn't happand at simple package like `pip install clock` (simple clock package from githab;just to check pip working)

I wanted to make a virtual enviroment but `pip install virtualenv` gave me the same problem.
I think that finally I succeed to install virtualenv by the command:

```
pip install https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/tarball/master
```

(but I not sure because all of my tries)

- I created new environment but still I couldn't install pyinstaller pack and I got the same error
- on the new env. I get the same *EnvironmentError* at `pip install clock` command (the simple pack, just to check pip).

So maybe something in communication from pip to my computer isn't correct.. maybe my programs need update? I updated pip to last version.
What do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I put command in the new environment that I made:

```
pip install --upgrade pip==10.0.1
```

and I installed the older version of pip

that way I successfully installed **PyInstaller pack!!**

for everyone know :)